# Should one use dashes or underscores when naming a gem with more than one word?

Tags: ruby, naming-conventions

I'm confused about what the gem naming convention is when the gem name has more than one word.

- thinking-sphinx is the name of the gem, but the base *.rb file for this gem is lib/thinking_sphinx.rb (underscores)
- acts-as-taggable-on is the name of the gem, and the base *.rb file is called lib/acts-as-taggable-on.rb (hyphens)
- factory_girl uses an underscore in both the gem name and in the name of the base *.rb file

Does it matter if one uses underscores or hyphens? Is any emerging consensus here?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Eric Hodel has a blog post on this: [A Project Naming Recommendation](https://web.archive.org/web/20090525085426/http://blog.segment7.net/articles/2009/05/20/a-project-naming-recommendation)

> Rails solidified the convention of
>   mapping CamelCase class names to
>   underscored file names (class
>   IMAPProcesor is defined in
>   imap_processor.rb). Using underscored
>   gem names makes it easy for people to
>   figure out what file to require (same
>   as the project name) or what class
>   name to look for in ri.
>
> If I have a plugin gem or an extension
>   I’ll tack on the sub-project’s name
>   with a dash. If I wanted to add a new
>   handler for imap_to_rss for Chase bank
>   email, the gem would be named
>   imap_to_rss-chase.

Comment: This is consistene with the reccommendation given in the official Ruby Gems Guides -[Consistent Naming](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#consistent-naming).

Comment: What about yajl-ruby or bcrypt-ruby, which are Ruby wrappers for existing C libraries? I do want a simple require 'bcrypt' inside my code, but I don't want to name my github project "yajl" or "bcrypt" because these (maybe) are already taken for the original C libraries.

Comment: This link to Eric Hodel's article is now dead. I tried to find it online, but after 3 google minutes didn't manage to do so.

Answer (score 40):

Following the advice [here](http://guides.rubygems.org/name-your-gem/), here is a table of how things would break down:

| Gem name | Require statement | Main class or module |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `fancy_require` | `require 'fancy_require'` | `FancyRequire` |
| `ruby_parser` | `require 'ruby_parser'` | `RubyParser` |
| `net-http-persistent` | `require 'net/http/persistent'` | `Net::HTTP::Persistent` |
| `rdoc-data` | `require 'rdoc/data'` | `RDoc::Data` |
| `autotest-growl` | `require 'autotest/growl'` | `Autotest::Growl` |
| `net-http-digest_auth` | `require 'net/http/digest_auth'` | `Net::HTTP::DigestAuth` |

Comment: I created a gem named tout_suite, but I still had to require it with `require 'tout/suite'`. Any ideas why? I'm using ruby 2.0 and rails 4.1.1

Comment: @gardenofwine, What was the main class or module? What did the file structure of your gem look like? Those things dictate what the gem 'should' be named, not the other way around.

Comment: This just worked fine for me.. I created gem called calabash-shared and i had to require 'calabash/shared'  - check this article for creating gems http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/04/08/how-to-build-a-ruby-gem-with-bundler-test-driven-development-travis-ci-and-coveralls-oh-my/