# Ruby gem naming conventions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I'm creating a ruby gem and I've noticed that there doesn't seem to be (to my knowledge) a naming convention for gems. For example, I've seen both:

```
gem 'foo-bar'
gem 'foo_bar'
```

Is there some kind of definitive guide/convention for the naming of ruby gems?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should one use dashes or underscores when naming a gem with more than one word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687659/should-one-use-dashes-or-underscores-when-naming-a-gem-with-more-than-one-word)

Comment: might help https://shivab.com/blog/ruby/2019/08/30/convert-your-ruby-script-to-a-ruby-gem/

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The dashed version is for extensions on other frameworks, like `rspec-rails` and the underscore is for part of the normal gem name and should be camelcased in your classes.

So if you have a gem named `foo_bar`, the class/module should be named `FooBar`. If that gem should have a rails extension which ships as a different gem, it should be called `foo_bar-rails` and the module should be called `FooBar::Rails` and it should be required as `require "foo_bar/rails"`

This convention is also what Bundler tries to require.

Admittedly, this convention is not always followed. `jquery_rails` should actually be `jquery-rails` and `factory_girl_rails` should be called `factory_girl-rails`. But hey, not everything is perfect.

RubyGems convention docs:

- [Naming gems](http://guides.rubygems.org/name-your-gem/)
- [Naming patterns](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/)
- [Make your own gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/)

Comment: This is bolstered by the rubygems patterns docs [here](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/).

Comment: An rather old but interesting conversation about this topic can be found in the `bundler` GitHub repo itself: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/1255

Answer (score 5):

Turns out that this is answered pretty clearly and succinctly in the rubygems docs: http://guides.rubygems.org/name-your-gem/

(This may be a recent doc addition because I recall searching for this info in the past and not finding it.)

Answer (score 4):

The one advantage is the convention of collapsing `foo_bar` into module or class `FooBar` as far as autoloaders go. `foo-bar` doesn't have a default equivalent.

Generally the underscore version is preferable from a `require` perspective, but the dashed version does come across as more readable so it tends to get used often.

Comment: The dashed version is more readable‽  It looks completely wrong to me, in what language can identifiers have dashes in them?

Comment: @Nemo157 - e.i. in CLIPS. I used to program in it and having dashes in identifiers was a nice thing to have. You did not need to press <SHIFT+"-"> to get "_"  and you could write something like: purple-cow_painter-module, cat_painter-module (I used _ to more separate things than -)

Answer (score 4):

In a recommendation of @svenfuchs:

- **underscore** => camelized
- **hyphen** => name::space

https://twitter.com/svenfuchs/status/135773593526206464

But it's true that I still see non-coherence behaviors like:

```
gem 'my_gem`, :require => 'my-gem'
```

https://twitter.com/#!/svenfuchs/status/135784542819713024