# Which files are required by Bundler.require?

Tags: ruby, bundler, dependency-management

If I have a `Gemfile` with these contents:

```
gem 'my-plugin'
```

Which files of `my-plugin` are required by `Bundle.require`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bundler.require` only makes one require statement per Gem. It's up to the Gem to require additional files from the top-level file.

It determines which file to require for each Gem based on a [standard naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958904/ruby-gem-naming-conventions):

- Gems should use underscores to separate words.
- Hyphens turn into slashes when requiring. This is used to create extension Gems that add files in a subdirectory (e.g., `rspec-rails`, which you require with `require 'rspec/rails'`).

So, in this case, it would `require 'my/plugin'`, which is probably not what you intend. By convention, your Gem should be named `my_plugin` with an underscore and should have a top-level file in its `lib` directory named `my_plugin.rb` that requires other files in your Gem.

If you can't change the name of the Gem, you can override the default require statement with a line like this:

```
gem 'my-plugin', :require => 'my_plugin'
```

If you need to require more than one file from the Gem, you're better off adding explicit require statements to your app rather than relying on `Bundler.require`.